# Python XML modifying by ElementTree destroys the XML structure

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am using Python V 3.5.1 on windows framework in order to modify a text inside , the modification works great but after saving the tree all the empty tags get destroyed as the following example:

```
<HOSTNAME></HOSTNAME> Is being changed to <HOSTNAME />
```

child with a text between the tags looks good:

```
<HOSTNAME>tnas2</HOSTNAME> is being changed to 
<HOSTNAME>tnas2</HOSTNAME> which is the same as the source.
```

The source XML file is:

```
<ROOT>

    <DeletedName>

        <VERIFY_DEST_SIZE>Y</VERIFY_DEST_SIZE>

        <VERIFY_BYTES>Y</VERIFY_BYTES>

        <TIMESTAMP>XXXXXXXXXDeletedXXXXXXXXXX</TIMESTAMP>

        <EM_USERS>XXXXXXXXXDeletedXXXXXXXXXX</EM_USERS>

        <EM_GROUPS></EM_GROUPS>

        <LOCAL>

            <HOSTNAME></HOSTNAME>

            <PORT></PORT>

            <USERNAME>XXXXXXXXXDeletedXXXXXXXXXX</USERNAME>

            <PASSWORD>XXXXXXXXXDeletedXXXXXXXXXX</PASSWORD>

            <HOME_DIR></HOME_DIR>

            <OS_TYPE>Windows</OS_TYPE>

        </LOCAL>

        <REMOTE>

            <HOSTNAME>DeletedHostName</HOSTNAME>

            <PORT>22</PORT>

            <USERNAME>XXXXXXXXXDeletedXXXXXXXXXX</USERNAME>

            <PASSWORD>XXXXXXXXXDeletedXXXXXXXXXX</PASSWORD>

            <HOME_DIR>XXXXXXXXXDeletedXXXXXXXXXX</HOME_DIR>

            <OS_TYPE>Unix</OS_TYPE>

            <CHAR_SET>UTF-8</CHAR_SET>

            <SFTP>Y</SFTP>

            <ENCRYPTION>Blowfish</ENCRYPTION>

            <COMPRESSION>N</COMPRESSION>

        </REMOTE>

    </DeletedName>

</ROOT>
```

the code is:

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from shutil import copyfile
import datetime

def AddAuthUserToAccountsFile(AccountsFile,RemoteMachine,UserToAdd):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    today = str(today)
    print(today)
    BackUpAccountsFile = AccountsFile + "-" + today
    try:
        tree = ET.parse(AccountsFile)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        copyfile(AccountsFile,BackUpAccountsFile)
    except:
        pass
    root = tree.getroot()
    UsersTags = tree.findall('.//EM_USERS')
    for UsersList in UsersTags:
        Users = UsersList.text
        Users = UsersList.text = Users.replace("||","|")
        if UserToAdd not in Users:
            print("The Users were : ",Users, "--->> Adding ",UserToAdd)
            UsersList.text = Users + UserToAdd +"|"
    tree.write(AccountsFile)
```

Appreciate for any help to pass this strange scenario.

Thanks,
Miki

Comment: `<HOSTNAME></HOSTNAME>` is exactly the same as `<HOSTNAME/>`

Comment: yes but my application cannot read it, it looks inside the tags so if there no open tag and close tag it cannot read it.

Comment: Well then you have made a big mistake when writing your application.

Comment: Its not mine unfortunately, it is Control-M, well known Production scheduler by BMC. i have to deal with that somehow, any chance to keep the structure as happens when the tag is not empty?

Comment: I have no idea what that is but you should file a support request.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found the solution  - 
just adding method = "html" to the tree.write line it keeps it as needed.

```
tree.write(AccountsFile,method = 'html')
```

Thanks.